# automatic restarting of servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, ups

We have 5 physical servers currently in operation. Two of them are virtualised and other 3 terminal servers are normal servers running 2003 servers and XP. After a power failure, virtualised servers( Esxi) restarted automatically while terminal server got turned off. So i had to physically turn them ON. Is there any way to enable auto-restart for these terminal servers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the hardware you are using most server brands have something like a ILO or DRAC, they can be configured to shutdown and power up servers in the manner that you are after.  You need to check to see if you servers have something like that.  Here is some information about the Dell DRAC cards

http://www.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/power/en/ps2q02_bell?c=us&l=en

Another way is via the UPS(if you have one) as an example APC has this type of feature, but you need to look at what you have and base your research on how to do what you want based off that information.

Answer (score 1):

Check your machine's BIOS. There is usually an option that controls how the system will behave when a power failure occurred. Typically, you want to change that setting from "do nothing" to "automatically turn on when power is applied".

Unfortunately, details changes from BIOS version to BIOS version so I can't give you more details about what that option is called, but it should be in the power management options.